# Checking User location every 5 minutes javascript

Tags: javascript, google-maps, parse-platform

So I think this solution will work but just wanted to see if there was something a bit more elegant. So I want to allow a user to "check in" to a location and once they have done so I want to see if they have remained in that location. I would check about every 5 minutes. Once they have checked out then I could stop checking. The goal is to get the total time spent at a store. I am using the Javascript SDK for Parse. This is the basic jist of my solution not a complete solution. Using a while loop to check a users location and to continue to do so as long as they remained checked in. Thanks for any suggestion and help! (Also I am using Google maps api to get store location). Just to be sure I am asking more if my approach is correct not if my code is correct.

```
checkIn: function(){

store_location = "something predefined";
Parse.GeoPoint.current({
    success: function(point){

        var user_location = new google.maps.LatLng(point.latitude,point.longitude);
        if(user_location = store_location){
            this.checkedIn();
        },
    }

});
},
checkedIn: function(){
///run loop while the user is still checked in 
///increment total time by 5 min every time loop is called

var checked_in = true; 
total_time = 0;

while(checked_in){
    setTimeout(function(){
        var user_location = new     google.maps.LatLng(point.latitude,point.longitude);
        if(user_location = store_location){
            total_time=total_time + 5
        }else{
            checked_in = false;
        }
    }, 3000000)
}
```

}

Comment: The while loop won't work at all.  It will just spin in the while loop, creating `setTimeout()` timers until your system is exhausted of resources.  No timeout will ever run.  This just simply isn't a way you can program in javascript.  You must set a timer, then when that timer fires, you decide whether you want to keep going and set another timer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
window.setInterval(function(){
        var user_location = new     google.maps.LatLng(point.latitude,point.longitude);
        if(user_location = store_location){
            total_time=total_time + 5
        }else{
            checked_in = false;
        }
    },3000000);
```

Comment: Oh ya that is so much better. Thanks! I am a java-script noob

Comment: Did you mean to use just `setInterval`, and need to remove the `setTimeout`?

Comment: I believe your right Phrogz but he might have just been confused by how I wrote it. setInterval(function(){doSomething()},3000); Is the correct implementation

Answer (score 0):

instead of using the while and setTimeout, why dont you use setInterval? i think it is easier and simplify the code

Comment: Yep your right. I just didnt even know about setInterval. New to javascript